# How to load emacs-lisp-mode-hook only when visiting files with .el suffix

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have developed some custom extensions to `emacs-lisp-mode`. The entry point to these extensions is via the function `my-elisp-mode-setup`. These extensions should only be available when visiting buffers with Lisp code. I tried the following:

```
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'my-elisp-mode-setup)
```

However it turns out that this mode-hook  is executed for any file type, which leads to confusion with variables in other file-hooks..

To debug this case, I reduced my `~/.emacs` to the following:

```
(defun my-elisp-mode-setup ()
  (message "kkkkk"))
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'my-elisp-mode-setup)
```

Then, I run emacs from command line with `emacs t.txt` (where `t.txt` is any dummy file). So for this particular file (`t.txt`) I would not expect the hook to be run since `t.txt` is not a Lisp file.. However, in the `*Messages*` buffer I get:

```
kkkkk
For information about GNU Emacs and the GNU system, type C-h C-a.
```

indicating that the hook has been run (due to the `kkkkk` text)..

Comment: This seems strange. I have some `elisp` customization set up this way, and it works fine. What if you run `emacs -Q`, then evaluate your hook in `*scratch*`, then open `t.txt`? Maybe also check what modes you have enabled with `t.txt` open via `C-h m`. And what version of Emacs are you running?

Comment: Wait, is `kkkkk` added to `*Messages*` before or after you open `t.txt`? Your `*scratch*` buffer will trigger `emacs-lisp-mode-hook`, so maybe that's where it's coming from?

Comment: @Chris I am not sure.. Why does `*scratch*` trigger `emacs-lisp-mode-hook`?

Comment: By default, `*scratch*` uses `lisp-interaction-mode`, which derives from `emacs-lisp-mode`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you want is to do your `emacs-lisp-mode` stuff only for `*.el` files, then just have your stuff test `buffer-file-name` for a `*.el` match.  IOW, `my-elisp-mode-setup` (more properly called `my-.el-file-setup` presumably) would be a no-op unless the name of the file visited matched whatever pattern (e.g. `*.el`) you want.

Comment: Thanks! I will try this. By the way, which files triggers the hook `emacs-lisp-mode-hook` in the first place? (It seems like `emacs-lisp-mode` is run for files with extension `.el` but also the init file `~/.emacs` seems to trigger the mode..)

Comment: For instance, for some modes, it seems like Emacs also looks at the contents of the file, and not only the file name extension. For instance in `sh-mode` for editing shell scripts, even if the file name does not have an extension `.sh` it still enters `sh-mode` if the first line in the file is `#! /bin/sh`..

Comment: @HåkonHægland, yes, Emacs supports enabling modes by file name or by content. Have a look at, e.g., `C-h v magic-mode-alist`.

Comment: If you start with `emacs -Q` then `magic-mode-alist` is `()`.  Any buffer that you visit that is in `emacs-lisp-mode` invokes `emacs-lisp-mode-hook`.  You can always add `debug` to that hook, to see where it is invoked: `(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'debug)`.  Or you can just examine how you start Emacs and what files you visit etc.